Disturbing ad with black circles and crosses
This ad has been showing a lot in the ads column to the right:



It's massive, ugly and disturbing with its crosses in circles.
I have tried using the "report this ad" link but nothing has come out of it.
It may be that the crosses are meant to be small and in the corners and serve as a way to close the respective block, but that is not what happens.

Isn't it some kind of indication of a broken image link?

@PeterMortensen seems like the image link is correct. But the image tag is unconstrained and set to fill as much content as possible. If the image is an SVG, then it just scales up seamlessly (rather than stretch abnormally or even remain at its own maximum size). So, more of broken styling than an image link. Although the "dismiss this company" is a bit suspicious - it might be the alt text of an image which is missing.

What ever happened to just simple non-interactive, non-tracking rectangular GIF banner ads? SMH
